# set browser as my website as homepage for firefox using nsis

Tags: firefox, nsis

i m building an installer thats set my website as the user's homepage in the firefox browser.
could use your help solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from JavaScript within browser, but not from command line. You can either change user.js, and add your preference about homepage there, but this will work only for new profiles, or add your own extension to FF, which will change the homepage.

Comment: cant i rewrite the user's js file using nsis or some other script by only installation and not entering the browser?

Comment: You can, but this new preference will be active only for new profiles created after this change, Current profiles will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" "Start Page" "http://google.com/"

${SubstiteInstallRdf} "$ENGINEDIR\defaults\preferences\prefs.js" "extensions.Plugin.HomePage" "pref($\"extensions.Plugin.HomePage$\", $\"http://google.com/$\");$\n"
```